# How can I catch connection exception using Spring RabbitMQ and MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, exception, rabbitmq

I'm using Spring and I'm getting the exception when the RabbitMQ is down the exception is thrown. I want to be able to catch it in order to print anything like "Retrying Connection".

```
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:62) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:510) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:751) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:215) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2085) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2058) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2038) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueInfo(RabbitAdmin.java:407) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:391) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.attemptDeclarations(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1820) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1801) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.initialize(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1337) [spring-rabbit-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1183) [spring-rabbit-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:60) ~[amqp-client-5.7.3.jar!/:5.7.3]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1113) ~[amqp-client-5.7.3.jar!/:5.7.3]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1063) ~[amqp-client-5.7.3.jar!/:5.7.3]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connect(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:526) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:473) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
```

The same happens with MongoDB when losing connection which I would like do the same.

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: mongo: Name does not resolve
            at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:211) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.10.1.jar!/:na]
            at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:75) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.10.1.jar!/:na]
            at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.10.1.jar!/:na]
            com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:126) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.10.1.jar!/:na]
            at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:131) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.10.1.jar!/:na]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mongo: Name does not resolve
            at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
            at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1277) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
            at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:203) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.10.1.jar!/:na]
            ... 5 common frames omitted
```

Is there a way to catch them using spring?

Answer (score 0):

The [`ConnectionFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/connection/ConnectionFactory.html) interface which can be injected in your rabbitmq configuration allows [setting an instance](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/connection/ConnectionFactory.html#addConnectionListener-org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionListener-) of the [`ConnectionListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/connection/ConnectionListener.html) interface. This interface provides 3 useful methods for monitoring connections:

```
// connectionFactory is injected connection factory of type ConnectionFactory

connectionFactory.addConnectionListener(new ConnectionListener() {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Connection connection) {
    log.info("Method onCreate was called! Info about connection {}", connection);
  }

  @Override
  public void onClose(Connection connection) {
    log.info("Method onClose was called! Info about connection {}", connection);
  }

  @Override
  public void onShutDown(ShutdownSignalException signal) {
    log.info("Method onShutdown was called! The connection will be restored automatically. Check the exception below for more info.", signal);
  }
});
```

The `onShutDown` method is a good place to inform everyone that you are trying to restore the connection.

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing something wrong but can't seem to make it work. The exception still print, and none of those methods seem to be called.